# Design pattern of translations files

Tags: zend-framework, design-patterns, translation

I'm developping an international Website based on [`PHP ZendFramework 1.12`](http://framework.zend.com/),
and I'm going to use [`Zend_Translate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.html) for managing my translations.

My translations will be put into PHP array `key=>value` like this : (one file per language)

```
<?php
return array( 
    'key'   =>  'translation',
    'key2'   =>  'translation2',
);
```

**My question is :**

What is the best way to manage keys into this files?

**My opinion is :**

In first hand, I could use **default language as keys**. Something like :

```
'Submit'  => 'Valider',
'Share'   => 'Partager',
//...
```

In other hand, I could use **special keys** to be able to directly found where does this text appear like :

```
'label_loginForm_login'     =>  'Login',
'button_mixed_submit'   =>  'Submit',
'links_mixed_share'     =>  'Share',
//...
```

But in this option, what is the best tree I could use for keys?
How many levels ('type' / 'placement' / 'action' ...)?

And for each level, how many items?

Example for level 'type'

- label : used for standard text
- text : used for long label with multiple sentances
- links : used for links label
- button : used for buttons label
- mixed : used for few things
  ...

For information, I'm going to make a module to help the translation.
It will be done using database, and PHP arrays will be created automatically for perf issue.

Comment: I would go for the first option. By doing this you will eliminate dupilcate words. If someone else working on your project then the second option might not make sense to him. I would also suggest placing the key, value pairs into a non array and more readable format like an ini or txt so dummies can edit it easily.

Comment: I've edit my post to answer you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, I would prefer the second option for **two reasons**.

1- By keeping in mind that you'll be translating validators error messages (which are keyed in a way like `regexNotMatch`), your second option will be homogeneous with the already set keys.

2- Also, with this option, you will avoid having `long phrases` as keys. For example :

```
return array(
    'confirmation_mail_sent' => 'Message here'
);

return array(
    'Your validation email has been sent. Please click on the link and ... bla bla bla bla' => 'Message here'
);
```

As you can easily notice, the first example is much more readable than the second one.

Hope my opinion is clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what about the structure? How can I choose the name of each key?

Comment: @JoDev There is not an exact `"implementation"`. It's up to you to think about this. You need to set an unique way on the whole project.